# View a sortable list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of workers on a page with all of their information. I want to be able to have a drop down list that selects the workers name and then you can view only that persons information. My loop for the show function looks like this:

```
<% @comp_times.each do |comp_time| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comp_time.name %></td>
    <td><%= comp_time.date_worked %></td>
    <td><%= comp_time.hours_earned %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', comp_time %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comp_time_path(comp_time) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comp_time, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know how to sort on the name, just not sort in the sense of only showing the worker that I want to see and not showing all the other ones that I don't need at the time.

Comment: You must make a filter get method on your controller. You must send a params for each worker i.e. the worker id from your view. Then on your controller you must filter this id and save on instance variable. After you can show it on your view with your instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag comp_times_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```